# What is a Planetnik?

Tags: folklore, slavic

From what I gathered, a Planetnik seems to be an air spirit that is somehow associated with [Perun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perun), the Slavic god of thunder and lightning. However, my sources are not particularly credible, sometimes contradictory and fail to mention any actual tales featuring the creature.

What exactly is a Planetnik? What does it look like, and what are its main properties? How is one created? What is its relationship with Perun, if any?

Comment: Lets use our old "friend" Greekmythology.com! http://www.greekmythology.com/pictures/Myths/Figures/153322/planetnik/

Comment: just another damn way to demote poor Pluto. No respect, I tell you.

Comment: @bleh The english description there is taken from a site called "f--kyeahstrangemythology". Not entirely sure how trustworthy the information is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the abstract a paper published in an (apparently) respectable academic journal (2010): the russian original '*planetnik*' is rendered as '*hobgoblin*':

> In the regions of Orawa and Podhale, among the local elders, beliefs
>   about hobgoblins , able to bring or mitigate thunderstorm, survived up
>   to this day. The hobgoblins are supposed to travel on clouds,
>   perceived as dragons, and depending upon peasants' fulfillment of
>   request for food, or failure to fulfill one, are able to either
>   destroy or protect the harvest. This work discusses features and
>   properties of the hobgoblins, including their relation to the Lateran
>   ringing tradition. The hobgoblins occur also in fiction literature,
>   which enables a discovery of the topos of naming ordinary people "a
>   hobgoblin".

The [paper](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/planetniki-v-oravskih-i-podhalyanskih-verovaniyah) is online in Russian.